# Set property value outside Knockout view model definition

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a Knockout view model defined like this:

```
function viewModel () {
    var self = this;

    self.myName = ko.observable();
    self.myValue = ko.observable("10");
};
```

Now I needed to change a value of the view model when a link was clicked, like this:

```
$('a.treeitem').live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    viewModel.myValue("20"); // this line does not work
});
```

However, I can't find out the correct way of setting the value, Chrome console shows the following message:
*Uncaught TypeError: Object function viewModel() { ... } has no method 'myValue'*

Comment: Don't use `live()` anymore :) it's deprecated. It's better to use `on()`. See the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) page for more information on the deprecation

Comment: Nice! I've changed my code from live() to on(). Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can save the view model as a variable like this:

```
window.vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$('a.treeitem').live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.vm.myValue("20");
});
```

Whenever you read from `window.vm` you'll be reading from that actual instance of the viewModel object

Comment: When trying to use this to write a boolean value in the form of `vm = new vm(listOfObjects);` and `vm.Expired(true);` (in other words, to add a boolean value), it says "Function expected` as the error.  Plain text can be written as you describe.

Comment: @vapcguy are you overwriting your vm class by assigning to a window variable called vm? Can you try renaming your view model class to something other than vm?

Comment: I actually had a different name than `vm` but was just using that here in my comment since that was the syntax in the example, for simplicity.  It was more about finding out why booleans couldn't be saved like that.  I also tried `vm.Expired = true;` and `vm.Expired = "true";` but got `'length' is null or not an object`.  But I could hard-code any string field just fine using the syntax in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what I want to do can be done inside the view model definition, so I can change my code to this:

```
function viewModel () {
    var self = this;

    self.myName = ko.observable();
    self.myValue = ko.observable("10");

    $('a.treeitem').live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self.myValue("20");
    });
};
```

Now everything works fine. Sometimes, the right way **really** is the easy one.

Comment: Don't you mean `self.myValue("20")`?

Comment: This looks kind of strange.The viewmodel is meant to not have any dependencies on the UI. The code in the accepted answer is more MVVM like.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner, that's true. This was my first hack, before getting the *right* answer.

Comment: this answer helped me figure out that the answer I need is `viewModel.myValue("20")` u, using the example here.