# Express.js/socket.io/knockout.js simpleGrid update throught socket.io

Tags: express, knockout.js, socket.io

i'm development a application using express/socket.io/knockout.js, it's my first time using knockout.js, to be exact i'm using simpleGrid example from knockout live example, but, with the difference that I get JSON from a socket in server.js, i don't have problem with this, i get json from server into client app, but I'm can't refresh/update simple grid with json recived. Grid is populated first time throught ajax call, but no update using socket.io and I can log using console.log json data coming from server .emit.

Cheers,
SR109

Here my index2.html, app client:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Title of the document</title>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout-3.4.2.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cs/sheetindex2.css">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class='liveExample'>   
                <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'> </div>
            </div>

            <script>

                var registros = [];
                var registros2 = [];

                $.ajax({            
                    url:"http://localhost:3000/json",
                    type: "get",
                    success: function(data){
                        registros = JSON.stringify(data);
                        registros2 = data;
                        //console.log(registros);
                        //console.log(registros2);
                        ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(registros2));
                    },
                    error: function(req, err){ 
                        console.log('my message' + err);
                    }
                }) 

                var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
                    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
                    console.log(items);
                    this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
                        data: this.items,
                        columns: [
                            { headerText: "Fecha", rowText: "fecha" },
                            { headerText: "Turno", rowText: "turno" },
                            { headerText: "1", rowText: "h1" },
                            { headerText: "2", rowText: "h2" },
                            { headerText: "3", rowText: "h3" },
                            { headerText: "4", rowText: "h4" },
                            { headerText: "5", rowText: "h5" },
                            { headerText: "6", rowText: "h6" },
                            { headerText: "7", rowText: "h7" },
                            { headerText: "8", rowText: "h8" }
                        ],
                        pageSize: 30
                    }); 
                };

                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
                console.log('Un cliente se ha conectado');
                socket.on('messages', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    PagedGridModel.items(data);
                    if(typeof registro2 != "undefined" && array != null && array.length != null && array.length > 0){
                        registros2=data;
                        ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(registros2));                        
                    }                    
                });
            </script>                
        </body>
    </html>
```

And my server2.js (i don't have problems with this):

```js
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var path = require('path');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'rootadmin',
    database: 'mecanizado'
})




var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

//app.use("/cs",  express.static(__dirname + 'client' + '/css'));
//app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + 'client' + '/js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'cs'));

app.route('/aplicacion').get(function(req,res){
    console.log(__dirname + '/index2.html');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index2.html');
});

app.route('/resultado').get(function(req,res){
    res.send("resultado1");
    res.end();
});

app.route('/usuario').get(function(req,res){
    res.json({'results': 'parametro'});
    res.end();
});

app.route('/json').get(function(req,res){

    //connection.connect();
    //connection.query('SELECT * FROM mecanizado.isla1', function(err,rows,fields){
    connection.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%Y-%m-%d') AS fecha, turno, h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8 FROM mecanizado.isla1 order by fecha desc, FIELD(turno,'mañana','tarde','noche') desc", function(err,rows,fields){
        res.json(rows);
    });
    //connection.end();
});



var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server started on port');
});
var io  = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //socket.emit('messages', { hello: 'world' });
    //setInterval(()=>socket.emit('messages','mensaje'),1000);
    setInterval(()=>consulta(socket), 1000);

    /* socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log('cliente conectado');
        //setInterval(socket.send('${new Date()}'), 1000);
        setInterval(socket.emit('messages','mensaje'),1000);
    }); */

  });

function consulta (socket){
    connection.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%Y-%m-%d') AS fecha, turno, h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8 FROM mecanizado.isla1 order by fecha desc, FIELD(turno,'mañana','tarde','noche') desc", function(err,rows,fields){
        //res.json(rows);
        console.log(rows);
        socket.emit('messages',rows);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need access to the actual instance that you used to apply bindings on the HTML. Only then can we modify the values. For this we need to save the instance in a variable. I have done that like this: `window.vm = new PagedGridModel(registros2);`

```
         $.ajax({            
                url:"http://localhost:3000/json",
                type: "get",
                success: function(data){
                    registros = JSON.stringify(data);
                    registros2 = data;
                    //console.log(registros);
                    //console.log(registros2);
                    window.vm = new PagedGridModel(registros2);
                    ko.applyBindings(window.vm);
                },
                error: function(req, err){ 
                    console.log('my message' + err);
                }
            }) 

            var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
                this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
                console.log(items);
                this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
                    data: this.items,
                    columns: [
                        { headerText: "Fecha", rowText: "fecha" },
                        { headerText: "Turno", rowText: "turno" },
                        { headerText: "1", rowText: "h1" },
                        { headerText: "2", rowText: "h2" },
                        { headerText: "3", rowText: "h3" },
                        { headerText: "4", rowText: "h4" },
                        { headerText: "5", rowText: "h5" },
                        { headerText: "6", rowText: "h6" },
                        { headerText: "7", rowText: "h7" },
                        { headerText: "8", rowText: "h8" }
                    ],
                    pageSize: 30
                }); 
            };

            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
            console.log('Un cliente se ha conectado');
            socket.on('messages', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.vm.items(data);
                if(typeof registro2 != "undefined" && array != null && array.length != null && array.length > 0){
                    registros2=data;
                    //ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(registros2));                        
                }                    
            });
```

Comment: Hi Ray, thank for you colaboration; I test you changes and no success, it seay: "ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAll' of undefined". About no rebind I understand,

Comment: Have a look at this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474185/set-property-value-outside-knockout-view-model-definition

Comment: Ray!!! you was right! problem solved!!! Remember bindin a unique time, y change observed data and to do that save instance with window.vm = viewModel() and change data where you need. Thanks!

Comment: Yep those two things are important :) That's great, glad it worked out!